# Strange behavior when using time(NULL)

Tags: c++, c

I'm using

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
```

to get the number of seconds since **1.1.1970**.

On two separate machines I get two different values, on one I get `1,419,120,000` on the other i get `7,812,616,799,348,535,896`.

It's important to say that the value was fine on both machines but suddenly stopped working. other machines run the same code for a long time without any issues.

In addition the project compiled as a 32 bit project whereas the project runs on sql server 2008 64 bit OS.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you display values?

Comment: also, there is no such OS like `sql server 2008 64 bit OS`

Comment: Sorry i meant Windows server 2008 OS. i'm using time_t object to display the value.
time_t current_time = time(NULL);
LONGLONG x = current_time;

Comment: If you want to correct a mistake in your question, you should exit the question, not just mention it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) is unspecified:

> The encoding of calendar time in `std::time_t` is unspecified, but **most** systems conform to POSIX specification and return a value of integral type holding the number of seconds since the Epoch. Implementations in which std::time_t is a 32-bit signed integer (many historical implementations) fail in the year 2038.

Looks like one of your systems gave what you expected the POSIX version to give and the other... didn't?

Note that [`std::time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) itself is also unspecified:

> ```
> typedef /* unspecified */ time_t;
> ```
>
> Although not defined, this is **almost** always an integral value holding the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC, corresponding to POSIX time.

Comment: That looks like the problem. The question is how did that happen.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) reference for [std::time()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time):

> The encoding of calendar time in std::time_t is unspecified, but most
>   systems conform to [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) and return a value of integral
>   type holding the number of seconds since the Epoch. Implementations in
>   which std::time_t is a 32-bit signed integer (many historical
>   implementations) fail in the year 2038.

So it seems the return value of time is not guaranteed to be " the number of seconds since 1.1.1970".

Comment: In my case that was a misunderstood behavior that was caused by bad licensing. That may cause additional functions not to work correctly not only time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was caused by windows licensing problem, we had to activate it after 30 days and we did renewed the licence but restart to our services didn't helped, but when i re installed our application i started to work.

Regards,
Pavel.